# Put JSON Body To Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to send this JSON object

```
{"from":{"Lat":30.075027703750937,"Lng":31.342577639657264,"Type":0},
"to":{"Lat":30.021339759652712,"Lng":31.284893204137528,"Type":0}}
```

to this Web API 2 method

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult PutTicketDestination(Guid Id, [FromBody] Location from, [FromBody] Location to)
```

where the location object is

```
public class Location
{
    public Location();
    public Location(double lat, double lng, LocationType type);

    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
    public LocationType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum LocationType
{
    Degree = 0,
    Radias = 1
}
```

but I get

> Can't bind multiple parameters ('from' and 'to') to the request's
>   content.

when I send this PUT request using Postman with the Id sent in the request URL

```
api/Tickets/PutTicketDestination/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000
```

can't really identify what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Make one class which includes all of parameters   and add FromBody attribute.

Comment: @UmutCatal well, I did work but is that really the case? I can't have multiple complex parameters in Web API methods?

Comment: here I would say why would you since it is not really a problem to introduce the new class. And for instance WFC services could not deserialize complex objects at all

Comment: @Jester  I don't like creating a model just to receive request for every Web API method that I have, that's a thing you can easily lose track of. I believe WCF can deserialize complex objects

Comment: Only to a certain level from my experience 2 levels deep when the message is json